# How do you bring back a destroyed activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter

I have an application that starts activity A. The user can then start service S from activity A. When a certain event happens, service S starts activity B. Activity B only has one button, and when pushed, should return to activity A. Everything works fine, except for when activity A was closed out using the back key. When the back key is pressed, instead of onPause, onDestroy is called. So when activity B is dismissed, I get sent back to the homepage instead of Activity A. So my question is, how can I make sure that Activity B reopens activity A if activity A is onPause, and also reopens the activity A when it's onDestroy has been called. I'm thinking to use intent filters, but I can't figure out to get the right combination. I do not want multiple instances of Activity A. Thanks for the help.

Comment: THere's a debug setting "Do not keep activities".  Do you have that checked?  If so, uncheck it.  The back button shouldn't call onDestroy, but if that option is set it will.

Comment: I checked that setting, it's not checked. In android apps, what is supposed to happen to the activity when the back button is pressed? @GabeSechan

Comment: Do you need to save activity A state?

Comment: I have a onsaved instance state for my activity for when it is paused and resumed. But when the activity is destroyed it doesn't save. It would be nice for the activity to save even when destroyed, but it is not necessary.

Comment: Check my answer, I think you can achieve what you want doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on activity A:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

or on Activity B, force it to start activity A,

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
    startactivity(i);
}
```

but since you implement the first one,
you dont need this last code.

I Hope it helps

Comment: 06-09 09:43:47.363: E/ActivityThread(18988): Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: I got this error when I added he onBackPressed method, not sure what happened...

Comment: try to force activity B to call allways activity A onBackPressed(). dont forget the `@override` signature

Comment: This works but it gives me the above in logcat, not sure if it's important

Comment: you have that warning/error everytime you go back? try to switch to `moveTaskToBack(false)` since its your head activity... maybe it helps

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need to save **A** state,
you can override [onBackPressed() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) in **B** to start **A** again.
And if you don't want multiple instances of **A**, use [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) when you start **B**.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, the above answer worked, and I'm sure this would work as well but i'd rather avoid the extra intents. I wish I could give up votes and the green check for both.

Comment: @user3700692 That's up to you. I think the error above will not show in my solution. Android is based on intents and actions, it won't be a poor design using it.